# Valid way to reuse coroutine scope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

So I have a class that has a lifecycle, containing a `start()` and an `stop()` function to start and stop the lifecycle. Now in that `start()` function I have to start a coroutine and in `stop()` I have to cancel it (The coroutine in `start()` runs infinitely until it is canceled, kinda like a socket listening for messages).

Because I would like a nice syntax to handle Coroutines I would like this class to implement `CoroutineScope`. The thing is that `start()` and `stop()` can be called multiple times.

My question is if this implementation is valid and does not contain any errors. The purpose is to make a reusable `CoroutineScope`.

```
class ReusableCoroutines() : CoroutineScope {

    private var job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job

    fun start() {
        job = Job()
        launch {
            println("Started and running!")
            while(true) {

            }
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        job.cancel()
        println("Stoped")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thing I can see happening here is your job gets started twice, and the first one never gets canceled, or something accessing your coroutineContext ending up with an obsolete `Job`. Also (just to be sure) - just because you sent `cancel` to a job doens't mean it's actually stopped, you could change your `while(true)` loop to `while(isActive)` to make sure it stops when cancelled.

Comment: You should make `job` nullable and fail if it's started twice (as @Joozd has mentioned) and also fail if `coroutineContext` is accessed while the scope is stopped (`get() = checkNotNull(job) { "scope not started" }`). You also need to consider if `start` and/or `stop` may be called concurrently as that can lead to race conditions. In addition you are breaking structured concurrency here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html -> Structured concurrency

Comment: Abandon hope of making a reusable `CoroutineScope`.  If you have a class with a lifecycle that can stop and start, make it contain a class with a single lifecycle that starts and stops only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I wouldn't do this. You don't get much out of reusable objects unless you are creating them by the thousands every seconds. I'd just create throwaway classes that are initialized on creation (without a `start` function) and then `cancel`led when `stop` is called. That being said this might work:

```kotlin
class ReusableCoroutines(
        private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
) : CoroutineScope by scope {

    private lateinit var job: Job
    private var stopped: Boolean = false
    private var started: Boolean = false

    @Synchronized
    fun start() {
        require(stopped.not()) {
            "Already stopped!"
        }
        require(started.not()) {
            "Already started!"
        }
        job = launch {
            println("Started and running!")
            while (true) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun stop() {
        require(stopped.not()) {
            "Already stopped!"
        }
        stopped = true
        cancel()
        println("Stopped")
    }

}
```

So you need some synchronization `@Synchronized` to prevent start being called from multiple threads and ending up in an inconsistent state.

You also take the `scope` as a parameter so you can get Structured Concurrency with this. You can also add `SupervisorJob` to `scope` to prevent the parent from being canceled when you cancel this scope.

Comment: Thanks, I will rethink my design choices and probably go with your first suggestion. Did I get it right that I would just have a class implementing CoroutineScope with a private member Job. If I would need to stop it I would call a function stop() which would cancel the Job and if I would need it again I would just create a new object of this class?

Comment: If you only have a single coroutine a `Job` is fine. The only thing that i'd change is to pass the scope as a parameter so that you can achieve Structured Concurrency.